# Storing Related Entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I new to core data, it would great if someone can give feedback/hint me with given requirement.

```
Entity A
{
property 1;
property 2;
property 3;
}
Entity B
{
property 1;
property 2;
property 3;

}
Entity C
{
EntityB ObjB; // pointing to Entity B
EntityA ObjA; // pointing to Entity A
property 1;
property 2;
property 3;
}
Entity D
{
EntityB ObjB; // pointing to Entity B
EntityA ObjA; // pointing to Entity A
property x;
property y;
property z;

}
```

Newly Inserted objected needs to be store into Entity C,Entity D with few more properties.

for isolation of insertion to main context below mentioned approach is used

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    objB = [[EntityB alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

As I have store objB & objA into EntityC, EntityD below method will be use.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityC" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        objC = [[EntityC alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
objC.objB = objC;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityD" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        objD = [[EntityD alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
objD.objB = objB;
```

then finally I will save all objects into main context.

```
  [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objB];
  [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objC];
  [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objD];
  [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Since I am not have much experience on core data I would like to know they way I am storing information is good or there is another approach to store data in mentioned scenarios.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
objC.objB = objC;
```

does not make sense and is probably a typo and you meant

```
objC.objB = objB;
```

This:

```
objD.objB = objB;
```

is correct and establishes the relationship between `objD` and `objB`.

These calls:

```
[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objB];
[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objC];
[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:objD];
```

are not needed, because `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` already
inserts the objects into the context.

Note that you should also define inverse relationships from *EntityA* and *EntityB*
to *EntityC* and *EntityD*, I cannot see from your question if you already did that.

Comment: Thanks for replying Martin, Yes I have setup the Inverse relation ship as well, I facing one issue that is "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts" Since I am using two different context, one for adding and another one for selecting the Object. I know it already been asked on stack overflow but I am not getting what extactly need to do. Can you please give some hint on that too?

Comment: @HimanshuIngole: First: I just noticed that you call `initWithEntity:...` with a nil context. In that case the `[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:` calls are actually needed. - Now to your question: You can establish relationships *only* between objects in the same context, but it is difficult to give a general answer to "how to do that?". One can merge changes in one context to another or use parent-child contexts.